# Not able to execute EXE files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-7-x64

[image]

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise with service pack 1 and with recent windows updates. PowerShell is also v5.0.

Lately I am not able to access any exe file ex: Notepad.exe or Calc.exe files from PowerShell Console.

I have executed below script also

```
set-executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Are you able to execute notepad in the normal manner (i.e., from the Start Menu)?

Comment: Note that `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is unrelated to _external executables_ such as `Notepad.exe` - it covers only PowerShell scripts and configuration files.

Comment: Running as administrator should not be required. I'd advise you to download `procmon` from microsoft (sysinternals), run that, run your command, stop procmon and filter/search for access denied messages. It should give you some good pointers as to what is happening.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yes I can run Notepad directly as well as from Command Prompt. The issue is only with PowerShell

Comment: Do you have a PowerShell profile established? If so, please edit your question to include the profile.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you don't have permission. Try in elevated mode(Runas Administrator)

Answer (score -2):

Try to run the console as Administrator :)